# CSS is not working in the ec2

Tags: html, css, amazon-ec2

This is the first time I try to use html/CSS on AWS ec2, I finally make ec2 display my html page but the CSS is not working. I have searched a lot of posts to figure the problem.

I got forbidden messages when I see the console on the web page.
[forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0nzH.png)
Some people said it's the permission problem, But I set directory permission like this:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-21-130 html]$
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root     ec2-user css
drwxr-xr-x. 2 ec2-user ec2-user image
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user indexChinese.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user index.html
```

And the image permission is like this:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-21-130 image]$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user About_PIC.JPG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user CHC_Pic.jpg
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user Education_Pic.JPG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user Email_pic.JPG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user FB_Pic.JPG
```

Here's my html with link tag within the head tag, please help and tell me where I did wrong.

```
<link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/JPG" href="/image/CHC_Pic.jpg" />
```

Everything works fine when I run in my localhost.
I don't know why my CSS and images don't work when I run my program in ec2. Btw, I use the command scp from my mac to the ec2.
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You'll need to troubleshoot your webserver (Apache/nginx) config.

Comment: Would you mind telling how to do it?

Comment: Share your webserver config.

Comment: I'm sorry. Webserver config? I'm not sure what you mean. I don't think I have webserver config. I just set up instance on ec2.

Comment: That instance has a webserver of *some* sort.

Answer (score 0):

On localhost, if you are using Windows, the extensions are not case sensitive, so the images working and load correctly, but on Web Server, the images and other files with extensions upppercase does't work if you are calling with lowercase and vice-versa, try change you file extensions to lowercase, or change on the CSS file.

Comment: OP mentions that he is using a Mac though, in which case this would fail even on localhost.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, I use Mac and I have changed the extensions like you said, but it's still not working.